# Trying to configure SSH server to use Google Authenticator 2FA on 22.04.3 Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, 22.04, ssh, two-factor-authentication

I followed this guide here https://www.techrepublic.com/article/enable-ssh-2fa-ubuntu-server/ to configure the first part **after setting up Google Authenticator on the system**. I couldn't log into my Ubuntu server through SSH because it asked for verification three times and then proceeded to ask me for the password three times.

The attempts *failed*. And have to reset everything to default, it works without it.

The section in that article with the title "How to configure the SSH daemon for 2FA" is the one that is getting hung with the process.

I updated and upgraded the packages and tried different things through askubuntu.com, the Digital Ocean site tried other sites, but I can't find a way to resolve it.

The method being used seems to act buggy with the SSH and possibly with pam? Even on a system that barely has anything installed by me on it along with apache2 and Docker.

The digital ocean guide I also tried. But
used `KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes` in the script instead of the one suggested in the digital ocean article. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multi-factor-authentication-for-ssh-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: What kind of 2FA are you trying to add? I got Google Authenticator to work without too much trouble.

Comment: I have Google Authenticator to work also it understands my keys when I use the TOTP code and it carries on without a problem.

But in the section that starts with "How to configure the SSH daemon for 2FA" in that article I shared. I followed the steps in it. And tried testing it is the one that is failing.

I haven't moved on to the other section yet with the title "How to enable 2FA with SSH Key Authentication". Sorry, I should have elaborated more on where it was messing up.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1498816/edit) and add the additional information.